# How to redirect from webapp to Google drive app

Tags: android, webview, google-drive-api, webapp2

I'm working with webapp. My requirement is while browsing, when I click on Google drive document link, that document has to be open in Google drive app instead of loading doc in my webapp

Answer (score 1):

This is a code snippet to launch google doc app which is installed on the device.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("doc.google.com")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the safest way to launch activity/app which can handle google doc.